# Writing .img to USB using dd results in corrupt primary GPT header

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb, gpt, dd

I have a 64GB USB 3.0 drive that I plan on installing bootable operating systems to for sysadmin purposes. My primary operating system is Mac OS X 10.11.

I have a copy of `ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso`. On my mac, I run the following command:

```
$ hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ubuntu.img ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso
```

As it says in the [ubuntu manual USB installation guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick) in order to make the `iso` file into a rewritable `img` file. That outputs the following:

```
Reading Driver Descriptor Map (DDM : 0)…
Reading Ubuntu 16.04 LTS amd64           (Apple_ISO : 1)…
Reading Apple (Apple_partition_map : 2)…
Reading Ubuntu 16.04 LTS amd64           (Apple_ISO : 3)…
.............................................................................
Reading EFI (Apple_HFS : 4)…
.............................................................................
Reading Ubuntu 16.04 LTS amd64           (Apple_ISO : 5)…
.............................................................................
Elapsed Time:  4.011s
Speed: 353.2Mbytes/sec
Savings: 0.0%
```

So I rename the newly created `ubuntu.img.dmg` to just `ubuntu.img` and attempt to use `dd` to write the contents to a disk:

```
0+22673 records in
0+22673 records out
1485881344 bytes transferred in 9.590071 secs (154939557 bytes/sec)
```

I then eject the USB and restart my Mac. Upon booting holding down <kbd>alt</kbd> and choosing the `EFI Boot` USB stick, I get a very brief message flashing on my screen that says `error: file '/boot' not found.` After the message disappears I get the standard GRUB menu and can boot into Ubuntu successfully.

I restart back into OS X again and run the `diskutil list` to get the partition information for the USB:

```
/dev/disk1 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *62.7 GB    disk1
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         4.1 KB     disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS                         2.4 MB     disk1s2
```

I wasn't sure this was the correct partition scheme, so I run `gdisk /dev/disk1` and get the following output:

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Caution: invalid main GPT header, but valid backup; regenerating main header
from backup!

Caution! After loading partitions, the CRC doesn't check out!
Warning! Main partition table CRC mismatch! Loaded backup partition table
instead of main partition table!

Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: damaged
```

My apologies for the long post, my question is: Where about's in this process is the error occurring (it's got 100% reproducibility on my end), and is there a way that I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I have no definitive solution, but I do have some observations:

- The [page you reference](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick) was written in 2010 and last updated in 2013. Thus, it's rather stale and may be completely inapplicable to Ubuntu 16.04.
- The `diskutil list` output on the converted disk shows that it uses the `Apple_partition_scheme` -- That is, Apple's APM partition table format, not GPT. Ideally, `gdisk` should detect this as such, but `hdiutil` seems to have created a variant of APM that `gdisk` doesn't recognize, hence the claim of a corrupt GPT.
- If you're trying to boot the Ubuntu installer in a regular way, try using `dd` directly from the `.iso` image to a USB drive, without first converting it with `hdiutil` or anything else. The Ubuntu `.iso` images are in a sort of Frankenstein's Monster format that *usually* boots correctly on USB drives. If that fails, use [Rufus,](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) [UNetbootin,](http://unetbootin.github.io/) or [Startup Disk Creator](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) to create a bootable USB drive. Note that the disk created in this way will be suitable for running the Ubuntu installer, but in most cases it will not be a good final installation medium; you'll want to boot the installer and then use it to install to a second USB drive.